# Properties.Settings.Default.variableName = textboxt.Text

Tags: c#, winforms

```
    private void Enable(TextBox temp, String system)
    {

        if (File.Exists(temp.Text))
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.system = temp.Text;
        }
        else
            do something here;
    }
```

Basically I'm trying to take a text box with some file path, check if it exists, if exists set the value of the Properties.Settings.Default.system to temp.text.

However I don't know how to use a variable name to reference the existing settings property.

Fairly new to this so any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: you mean like this? `Properties.Settings.Default["system"]`

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Mike Debela for the answer.... But if ran into a situation where you don't know the system, this code will help prevent some errors.

```
private void Enable(TextBox Temp, string system)
{
    // check that the property even exists
    bool propertyExists = Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Cast<SettingsProperty>().Any(p => p.Name == system);
    if (propertyExists)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default[system] = Temp.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        // create a new property
        var p = new SettingsProperty(system);
        p.PropertyType = typeof(string);
        p.DefaultValue = Temp.Text;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Add(p);
    }

    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Comment: currently just passing variables through manually with no input. Though thank you for the advice, my program may evolve to where I may need this.